# In Python Pandas, how can create this table, new row in the same column with the previous row and add the same row from other column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate this data frame:

```
diff               start                stop
--------------------------------------------------------
3456                 0                  3456
2345              3456+1              3457+1+2345
1234             3457+2345+1          3457+2345+1+1234
1222               .......             ........
7654               .......             ........
....               .......             ........
```

In Python, how can create this table, a new row in the same column with the previous row, and add the same row from other columns?

```py
df_sorted.loc[:,'start'] = df_sorted.loc[:,'start'] + df_sorted.loc[:,'diff']
```

Comment: I often use DataFrame.from_dict() ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict ) to generate new tables from an existing / data set, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for. Please split up your question sentence into several steps and describe in more detail what you're starting with and what you're expecting at each step.
Should be using 'stop' instead of 'start' on the left-hand side... but maybe I misunderstood?
Possibly DataFrame.cumsum() would help? I'm not sure where the +1 comes from in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the function [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

You can use:

```
df_sorted.loc[:, 'start'] = df_sorted.loc[:, 'start'].shift(1, fill_value=0) + df_sorted.loc[:, 'diff']
```